# Images Over lapping my navigation bar

Tags: html, css

Code of navigation bar

```
ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
    padding: 25px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: large;
}
```

and code of image

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    left: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
```

So when I scroll text smoothly hides behind navigation bar. but the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Toa0w.png)image overlaps the navigation bar

right now on my right the div of 'similar questions' is also overlapping the bottom black div

Comment: sorry i forgot to enter image description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to your `ul` and make sure it is higher than what the other elements have.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a `z-index` to the main navigation higher than the content scrolling. As mentioned.

But also you using `position: relative`on the image, if you also set its parents position to relative as well thi sway the image will stay within the main contents wrapper, and scroll beneath the menu with the rest of the content.